# Naming a Column using Variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I wish to calculate Ascending Points Diff for all players in a sweep over a series of games. I wish to have the first column name PD1 with the least Points Difference, PD2 next lowest and so on. I wish to do this using a variable which just adds the integer to the end of 'PD' based on the number of games. I keep getting an error when I add AS @ColumnName to the end of the Calculation.

```
USE [Rugby Pools]


DECLARE @counter int
DECLARE @MaxPlayer int
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(50)

SET @counter = (SELECT MIN([Player_ID]) FROM [dbo].[Players])
SET @MaxPlayer = (SELECT MAX([Player_ID]) FROM [dbo].[Players])


DECLARE @gamecounter int
DECLARE @MaxGame int
SET @gamecounter = (SELECT MIN([Game_ID]) FROM [dbo].[Match])
SET @MaxGame = (SELECT MAX([Game_ID]) FROM [dbo].[Match])
SET @ColumnName='PD'+@gamecounter

WHILE @gamecounter <= @MaxGame

BEGIN


WHILE @counter <= @MaxPlayer

BEGIN



SELECT     TOP (@gamecounter)   dbo.Players.Player_ID, dbo.Entries.Game_ID, ABS(ABS(dbo.Entries.Home_Score-dbo.Entries.Away_Score)-(dbo.Match.Home_Score-dbo.Match.Away_Score)) AS @ColumnName
FROM            Entries INNER JOIN
                         Match ON Entries.Game_ID = Match.Game_ID INNER JOIN
                         Players ON Entries.Player_ID = Players.Player_ID

                         WHERE dbo.Match.Home_Score IS NOT NULL AND dbo.Players.Player_ID=@counter

                         ORDER BY Players.Player_ID, PointsDiff1 ASC

SET @Counter += 1

                         END                        

SET @gamecounter += 1

END
```

Once working, I will be able to alter it to update a table which will allow me to provide a league table of players decided by wins, followed by best points difference over the course of the tournament.

Comment: you can't use variable for object  name  .. (columns and tables)   for these  you need  dinamyc sql

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: Dynamic SQL can be used to achieve dancing column names, but typically the code that consumes the data doesn't benefit from column names that keep changing. Why do you think this will simplify things? Perhaps there is a better approach to a larger problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your final query section to dynamic sql like this. It can be achieved only by dynamic sql.

```
 declare @query nvarchar(max)
 set @query = ' SELECT TOP (' + cast(@gamecounter as varchar(10)) + ') dbo.Players.Player_ID, 
               dbo.Entries.Game_ID, ABS(ABS(dbo.Entries.Home_Score-dbo.Entries.Away_Score)-(dbo.Match.Home_Score-dbo.Match.Away_Score)) AS ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + '
    FROM            Entries INNER JOIN
                             Match ON Entries.Game_ID = Match.Game_ID INNER JOIN
                             Players ON Entries.Player_ID = Players.Player_ID

                             WHERE dbo.Match.Home_Score IS NOT NULL AND dbo.Players.Player_ID= ' + cast(@counter as varchar(10)) + '
                             ORDER BY Players.Player_ID, PointsDiff1 ASC'

  sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.Sorry in the slow response, I was out with a long illness. Hopefully getting backup on a very small horse again.